# HTML table row span

Tags: javascript, html, object, html-table, ejs

I am iterating over an object having 3 items and sometimes the length of the object is more than 1. I want to have only 3 cols but when there is more than 1 object then it increases the number of cols. The row span must increase instead of cols.
I am using ejs template. How to ensure that when data length is more than 1, no. of cols remains the same and each item data render in a single row.

```
  <% value.cartItems.map(item =>{ %>
   <td><%= item.name %></td>
   <td><%= item.count %></td>
   <td><%= item.key %></td>
  <% })%>
```

***CART ITEM DATA for 2 Objects***

```
[
  {
    count: 1,
    key: 'ID02',
    name: 'Tiny Ganesh',
    pic: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/antique/image/upload/v1596196504/cklhq28mzm5b61hrwcve.jpg',
    price: '2070'
  },
  {
    count: 1,
    key: 'ID03',
    name: 'Ganesh With Kalash',
    pic: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/antique/image/upload/v1596196650/tiwxkkug3hms2unacike.jpg',
    price: '3570'
  }
]
```

***TABLE CODE***

```
<table class="responsive-table highlight ">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>Order Id</th>
                  <th>Address</th>
                  <th>Product</th>
                  <th>Product Count</th>
                  <th>Product Code</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
        <% data.map(i =>{%>
            <% for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(i)) { %>
                     <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td><%= value.orderDate %></td>
                        <td><%= value.orderId %></td>
                        <td ><%= value.address %></td>
                        <% console.log(value.cartItems)%>
                        <% if(value.cartItems.length == 1){ %>
                        <% value.cartItems.map(item =>{ %>
                            <td><%= item.name %></td>
                            <td><%= item.count %></td>
                            <td><%= item.key %></td>
                        <% })%>
                        <% }%>
                        
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
            <% } %>
        <% })%>
    </table>
```

Comment: Can you share the wrapping <table> and <tr> around it as well? It might have something to do with that.

Comment: Also what is the value of the cartItems object when it gives the unwanted behaviour?

Comment: @jlast Please check I have edited the question.

Comment: Two pointers: 
- Try to move the <tbody> outside the for loop.
- Add an else statement with empty <td> to ensure all the rows are filled

Comment: Moving tdbody out of the loop have no effect and about <td>,  didn't understand your point

Comment: you do an if check: `if(value.cartItems.length == 1){` to validate if the row has indeed one item. If it has multiple catitems (else) you need to add 3 empty '<td></td>' elements to match the amount of <th>

Comment: Also since you already checked if there is only 1 element, you can also directly use:
                            <td><%= value.cartItems[0].name %></td>
                            <td><%= value.cartItems[0].count %></td>
                            <td><%= value.cartItems[0].key %></td>
and remove the                         <% value.cartItems.map(item =>{ %>

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that there is always the same amount of table cells as there are headers. So you need to add an else, and you can remove the redundant map function:

```
    <table class="responsive-table highlight ">
        <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>Order Id</th>
                  <th>Address</th>
                  <th>Product</th>
                  <th>Product Count</th>
                  <th>Product Code</th>
              </tr>
        </thead>
        <% data.map(i =>{%>
           <tbody>
            <% for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(i)) { %>
                      <tr>
                        <td><%= value.orderDate %></td>
                        <td><%= value.orderId %></td>
                        <td ><%= value.address %></td>
                        <% if(value.cartItems.length == 1){ %>
                            <td><%= value.cartItems[0].name %></td>
                            <td><%= value.cartItems[0].count %></td>
                            <td><%= value.cartItems[0].key %></td>
                        <% } else { %>
                           <td></td>
                           <td></td>
                           <td></td>
                        <% }%>
                      </tr>
            <% } %>
           </tbody>
        <% })%>
    </table>
```

Comment: This way if object has length more than 1 then it will not render anything because of empty <td>. This didn't solve my purpose.

Comment: what would you want to happen if it has multiple cartitems?